# How do I setup ELK HTTP beat to send delta feed to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-beats

I have setup HTTP beat that polls an endpoint and stashes the data to logstash. I could see the events using a specific index on Kibana. The interval has been set to every 5 seconds.

However I want the ELK stack to capture data that are changed over time (delta feed) rather than all the data in every 5 seconds. Is there any way to do it?

My HTTPbeat.yml looks like this :

```
 httpbeat:

  hosts:
    # Each - Host endpoints to call. Below are the host endpoint specific configurations
    -
      # Optional cron expression, defines when to poll the host endpoint.
      # Default is every 1 minute.
      schedule: '@every 5s'

      # The URL endpoint to call by Httpbeat
        url: #sample end point
        method: get
        basic_auth:
         # Basic authentication username
           username: 
         # Basic authentication password
           password: 
        output_format: json
       #----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
        output.logstash:
       # The Logstash hosts
        hosts: ["localhost: 5400"]
```

The logstash.conf is as follows :

```
input {
    # Accept input from the console.
    beats {
        port => "5400"
    }
}

filter {
    # Add filter here. This sample has a blank filter.
}

output {
    # Output to the console.
    stdout {
            codec => "json"
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "test_jira2_idx"
    }   
}
```

If I hit the endpoint through postman, the JSON body is around 1.08 MB size. But while monitoring the Kibana index : test_jira2_idx, it is already 340MB in 1 hour and is constantly increasing.

This may be due to the fact that HTTP beat is constantly polling the same data every 5 seconds. Can anyone suggest the various alternatives to implement delta feed extract in ELK ?

I had a look into the HTTP_POLLER input for logstash - unsure if that can help.

Note : I am very new to ELK

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion, generate hash for response and every time check if the the hash is changed from previous response than only store it. (also add timestamp with stored document).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the noob question but the hash will be generated from Beats ? Any online resource ?